iOS Bluetooth connection, connect to two BLE speakers and stream audio
Bluetooth implementation demonstrating how I am connecting the BLE speakers and notify them to receive notifications for streaming. I can see there are connected from the iPhone settings, but when I play an audio file it plays on the phone speaker, and when I connect them directly from  the iPhone settings it plays from the Bluetooth speaker.
I want to connect the Bluetooth speaker from my application and play my audio file for it on the Bluetooth speaker. Is this possible? I want to connect both speakers and play the stream on both, but I would love to connect one of them first, then I can move to connecting two, one step at a time. Just help if you connect just one directly from the application and play the audio file.
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth
import UIKit
import AVFAudio

class BluetoothViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CBPeripheralDelegate, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    @Published var secondConnectedPeripheral1: CBPeripheral?
    @Published var firstConnectedPeripheral: CBPeripheral?
    @Published var connectedPeripherals: [CBPeripheral] = []
    private var characteristic: CBCharacteristic?
    private var secondcCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic?
    @Published var devices: [CBPeripheral] = []

    override init() {
        super.init()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {
        case .poweredOn:
            startScanning()
        default:
            print("Bluetooth state: \(central.state.rawValue)")
        }
    }

    func startScanning() {
        if centralManager.state == .poweredOn {
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])
        }
    }

    func stopScanning() {
        centralManager.stopScan()
        // Optionally restart scanning after a delay
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { [weak self] in
            self?.startScanning()
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String: Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            if !self!.devices.contains(where: { $0.identifier == peripheral.identifier }) {
                if let name = peripheral.name, !name.isEmpty {
                    self?.devices.append(peripheral)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("Connected to peripheral: \(String(describing: peripheral.name))")
        peripheral.delegate = self
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }

    func connectToPeripheral1(peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        if peripheral == secondConnectedPeripheral1 {
            centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)
        }
        firstConnectedPeripheral = peripheral
        connectedPeripherals.append(peripheral)
        centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: [CBConnectPeripheralOptionEnableTransportBridgingKey: true])
    }

    func startAudioStreaming() {
        guard characteristic != nil else {
            print("Audio characteristic not found")
            return
        }
        // Enable notifications
        // firstConnectedPeripheral?.setNotifyValue(true, for: audioCharacteristic)
    }

    func startAudioSecondStreaming() {
        guard let audioCharacteristic = secondcCharacteristic else {
            print("Audio characteristic not found")
            return
        }
        // Enable notifications
        secondConnectedPeripheral1?.setNotifyValue(true, for: audioCharacteristic)
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error changing notification state: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error discovering services: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        guard let services = peripheral.services else {
            return
        }
        for service in services {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error reading characteristic value: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDisconnectPeripheral error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Disconnected with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            firstConnectedPeripheral = nil
            secondConnectedPeripheral1 = nil
        }
    }

    func didTapDisConnect(peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        if peripheral == firstConnectedPeripheral {
            if let matchedPeripheral = connectedPeripherals.first(where: { $0.identifier == peripheral.identifier }) {
                firstConnectedPeripheral = nil
                connectedPeripherals.removeAll(where: { $0.identifier == matchedPeripheral.identifier })
                centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(matchedPeripheral)
            }
        } else if peripheral == secondConnectedPeripheral1 {
            if let matchedPeripheral = connectedPeripherals.first(where: { $0.identifier == peripheral.identifier }) {
                secondConnectedPeripheral1 = nil
                connectedPeripherals.removeAll(where: { $0.identifier == matchedPeripheral.identifier })
                centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(matchedPeripheral)
            }
        } else {
            connectedPeripherals.removeAll(where: { $0.identifier == peripheral.identifier })
            centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)
        }
        startScanning()
    }

    func connectToPeripheral2(peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        if peripheral == firstConnectedPeripheral {
            centralManager.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)
        }
        secondConnectedPeripheral1 = peripheral
        connectedPeripherals.append(peripheral)
        centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print(peripheral.name ?? peripheral.identifier.uuidString)
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error discovering characteristics: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        guard let characteristic = service.characteristics?.first(where: { $0.properties.contains(.write) }) else {
            print("No characteristic with write property found.")
            return
        }
        if peripheral == firstConnectedPeripheral {
            self.characteristic = characteristic
            startAudioStreaming()
        } else {
            self.secondcCharacteristic = characteristic
            startAudioSecondStreaming()
        }
        print(characteristic.service?.uuid ?? "Unknown service UUID")
        print(peripheral)
        print(characteristic.properties)
    }
}


Do not include your code as pictures. [edit] your question to include relevant code in a code block

First of all, source code as an image is a no-go. Secondly, audio is currently based on Bluetooth Classic, not Bluetooth LE.

i uploaded the code, from Bluetooth L.E 5.3 you can stream audio my device is 5.3 and a speaker thats why i  can connect to it from my application through Core Bluetooth.. but audio wont play on it

Did you setup your App required Entitlements, Signing&Capabilities -> Bluetooth, and the Info.plist with the Privacy - Bluetooth ... P.S edit your code it is not formatted properly, unreadable. See also this Apple link Bluetooth Classic device

@DanielJermaine your hardware may be able to do LE Audio, but your phone's operating system can't.

i did setup and i have watched the 2019 WWDC bluetooth video

@Risto my device is an iPhone device

@DanielJermaine have you ever seen a statement from Apple saying that any LE Audio profile will be supported?
